# fetch is not getting called when executing the test case

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I am writing a test case for a function called `getResource`.

```
export function getResource(uri: string, callback: Function, isJson: boolean): void {
  fetch(uri)
    .then((res) => (isJson ? res.json() : res.text()))
    .then(
      (result) => {
        callback({ isSuccessful: true, data: result });
      },
      (error) => {
        callback({ isSuccessful: false, error: error });
      }
    );
}
```

For that, I have written the test case like this

```
global.fetch = jest.fn(() =>
  Promise.resolve({
    json: () =>
      Promise.resolve({
        isSuccessful: true,
        data: { res: [] },
      }),
  })
) as jest.Mock;

describe("getResource()", () => {
  it("should call the callback function with the obj", () => {
    const mockCallback = jest.fn();
    getResource("/dummy_endpoint", mockCallback, true);
    expect(getResource).toBeCalledWith("/dummy_endpoint", mockCallback, true);
    expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith("/dummy_endpoint");
    // expect(mockCallback.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

Now the issue is when I execute this test, I get this error.

[image]

I am not sure why the fetch is not getting called with the URI argument. Kindly, share your thought on this. Thank you.

Comment: Make the function async and await the fetch promise.  Then await the call to getResource.

Comment: @StevenSpungin Not working. And then can accept two callbacks like resolve and reject.

Comment: imo it is working, just getting called after you call `expect`.  Because your are not awaiting your fetch, you wont get the result.  Make the `it` function async too.

Comment: FYI your `fetch` code should check `res.ok` to detect problems with the request. See http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html

Comment: @Phil Thank you for the blog and your answer. Let me check it. I will get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

In order to test asynchronous functions that accept callbacks, you need to make use of the `done` parameter

```ts
interface CallbackParams {
  isSuccessful: boolean;
  data?: any;
  error?: any;
}

const mockData = { res: [] }; // this can be literally anything
const mockJson = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockData);
global.fetch = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
  ok: true,
  json: mockJson,
});

describe("getResource()", () => {
  it("should call the callback function with the obj", (done) => {
    const endpoint = "/dummy_endpoint";
    const cb = ({ isSuccessful, data }: CallbackParams) => {
      try {
        expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(endpoint);
        expect(mockJson).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(isSuccessful).toBe(true);
        expect(data).toBe(mockData);
        done();
      } catch (err) {
        done(err);
      }
    };

    getResource(endpoint, cb, true);
  });
});
```

See https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#callbacks

---

This works for me with the following setup

- Typescript 4.8
- A default `tsconfig.json` generated via `yarn tsc --init` with the following modifications in `compilerOptions`

  ```js
  "lib": ["DOM"], // for `fetch` support
  ```
- `ts-jest` and `@types/jest`
- A default `jest.config.js` generated by `yarn ts-jest config:init`, ie

  ```js
  /** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
  module.exports = {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    testEnvironment: 'node',
  };
  ```

Comment: Hi @phil, the above solution is not working. I tried a lot of different things. Here is the code sandbox link for the error: https://codesandbox.io/s/jest-test-forked-l75soi?file=/utils.test.js

Comment: @AmrendraNath works absolutely fine for me locally. I suspect any issue you see on CodeSandbox are strictly due to sandbox limitations